# Cable modem and WiFi AP

Tags: cable-modem

the topology is like this: Ruckus AP is connected to Cable Modem which is connected to CMTS which is connected to Ethernet LAN network.

If Ruckus AP is connected to cable modem (CM), does the DOCSIS (CMTS or CM?) store MAC address of each WiFi client? If yes, where are they stored?

Comment: Does the Cable Modem have any IP routing functionality, or is it acting as purely a L2 bridge?

Comment: @u1686_grawity The frame arrives as Ethernet frame to the LAN side. I believe this would be the 'bridge' mode?

Comment: Not necessarily... on an Ethernet link, _all_ frames will be Ethernet frames, it's about what generates the framing. Do frames inbound from the LAN have the CM's own MAC address as source, or do they appear to come from the MAC address of CMTS or something else?

Comment: @u1686_grawity Frames arriving from CMTS to LAN side have MAC addresses of clients.

Comment: ...Are you sure they have client MAC addresses as _source_?

Comment: @u1686_grawity Wifi is local switched.

Comment: But I wasn't asking about that. I was asking about packets in the _other_ direction.

Comment: u1686_grawity You mean from LAN to Docsis?